# CCK NodeReference - Pass current user id as argument to selection view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I'm trying to create a view to limit the options available to a user for a CCK NodeReference field. I want to pass the current user's ID as an argument to the view that selects the options for the CCK NodeReference field. Basically when the user creates a new item, I only want them to be able to reference a node which they created (not someone else's node). I've got a view set up that accepts a user ID as an argument, but how do I pass the current user's ID to the view from the CCK NodeReference field?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the view, click on the user id argument and click provide default argument, select `User ID from logged in user`. Choose the "user" validator, and optionally select to restrict the view to particular roles.